# Trying to restore older Macbook Pro 13 and 15in

Tags: hard-drive, install, restore, dmg

Ok so im running out of ideas. i have two macbooks that im trying to restore. They both predate internet recovery and the hard drives were replaced. I do not have any disks for them so im trying to recover them using usb drives. I am currently using a 2019 macbook pro to create the drives. I was able to edit a dmg file of El Capitan on my machine to get the app in the applications folder. I was able to start the media creation using createinstallmedia in terminal but it usually errors out.

Couldn't mount dmg /Volumes/Install OS X El Capitan/Install OS X El Capitan.app/Contents/SharedSupport/InstallESD.dmg (error code 110)Mount of outer dmg failed.

What do i do or where do i go from here?

Comment: Did you get the latest version of the dmg from https://support.apple.com/HT211683 ?